# Where can I find ubuntu drivers for Asus?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers

I installed Ubuntu 14 on my Asus Q502LA laptop, and now I am missing a WiFi driver.
I can't seem to find a relevant driver to download. Does anybody know where I can find the needed drivers? can I find a Wifi driver from Intel?

Comment: Ubuntu should have installed a generic driver if there wasn't one specially provided for that WiFi. I would go to the Ubuntu forum and post this question there.

Comment: What specific wifi hardware (model number) do you need a driver for?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the same laptop. Plugged it into my router via ethernet cable and ran an update and upgrade
(`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`)
after a reboot, the new kernel fixed it right up.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in upstream http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-fixes.git/commit/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c?id=4f08970f5284dce486f0e2290834aefb2a262189

I think you should open a ticket in launchpad if you don't want to patch the kernel by hand.